# Partially merging files

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

I'm quite new to Powershell and have so far created a couple of scripts based of what I have found on various sites.
Now I want to expand my scripts further and have run into problems. I guess its not that diffucult to do what I want, but I dont seem to get it to work.

Scenario:
I have a file called from.csv that is automatically created with below info:

```
from.csv

Name,Mac
Server01,00:50:56:00:00:01
Server02,00:50:56:00:00:02
Server03,00:50:56:00:00:03
```

I also have a file called to.csv with below info:

```
to.csv

Name,Mac,IP
Server01,,192.168.0.1
Server02,,192.168.0.2
Server03,,192.168.0.3
```

What I now want to do is to get the correct (corresponding to the correct server) MAC-address from the "from.csv" file included to the correct column in the "to.csv" file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy, actually.

First you'll load your `from.csv`:

```
$from = Import-CSV from.csv
```

Then it's easiest if you create a lookup table from that data:

```
$servers = @{}
$from | foreach { $servers[$_.Name] = $_.Mac }
```

Then you can load `to.csv`:

```
$to = Import-CSV to.csv
```

And add in the missing data:

```
$to | foreach { $_.Mac = $servers[$_.Name] }
```

And save the result:

```
$to | Export-Csv to_result.csv
```